# Azure netcore webapp drops out downloading files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I have an azure netcore webapp hosting some static files (50mb to 400mb). I can get 11megabytes a second download however numerous people report the downloads get stuck at 40% and simply never work regardless of using cellular or cabled internet (various speeds).

The webapp is s1 standard.

I personally cannot repeat the error. I have tried slowing my connection using vpn with 1sec ping and it always seems to work but our users still get drop-outs constantly when connecting from the same region with fast internet.

2 questions, what causes downloads to get stuck when hosting static files in netcore on azure?

2nd question. How can I implement a FileResult with resumability do when it does drop out it just continues on again?

Comment: Have you the 'always on' setting activated? Why don't you use Azure blob storage for static files?

Comment: We did use azure blob but wanted authentication so we were streaming the files from azure and ran into drop-outs. We then changed to static files and still experienced drop outs. The server is kept alive by a keep alive so it never spins down